# Divisibility of a rational function

Tags: rational-functions

Problem

Determine coefficients $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
\dfrac{x^3+ax^2+bx-6}{bx^2+2x+a}
$$
is divisible by $x-2.$

- What is actually meant by divisible in this case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

> What is actually meant by divisible in this case?

It's not very clear... You could call this fraction "divisible by $x-2$" if you can factor $x-2$ in the numerator, but I have the feeling they might mean that you can factor $x-2$ in the numerator *and* the denominator, and thus simplify the fraction.

In that case, you don't have to perform the division which is a bit annoying with the parameters $a$ and $b$. Recall that a polynomial is divisible by $x-c$ if $c$ is a root of the polynomial so with $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx-6$ and $q(x)=bx^2+2x+a$, you want $p(2)=0$ and $q(2)=0$. This will give you a linear system of two equations in the parameters $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks, I already figure out that, but divisibility of a rational function can be understood two ways: the way you mentioned and such that, the rational function formed by division is a polynomial.